# sudo misinterpreting aliases

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo, alias

In my `~/.bashrc` I have the `alias link='ln -sf'` set, and it's working accordingly during my shell sessions.

However, for root protected locations, where I need to use `sudo` in the command beginning, it is throwing the following error:
`link: cannot create link '<$2>' to '<$1>': Operation not permitted`

What is exactly happening? How could I go around it?

Comment: The comand was `sudo link ~/my/destination/folder /fr`. Thus I tried to create a symlink at `/`, which isn't a read-only location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo` is an external command which doesn't know about your aliases. Only your shell knows about your aliases, and `sudo` is not part of it.

In this case I guess that `sudo` tries to run the `/usr/bin/link` binary, which on my Linux system is a simple command which always creates a *hard* link by invoking the `link(2)` system call:

```
$ link --help
Usage: link FILE1 FILE2
  or:  link OPTION
Call the link function to create a link named FILE2 to an existing FILE1.

      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

GNU coreutils online help: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/link>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) link invocation'
```

Comment: Ooow, I got it. So I suppose the simplest way to go around it should be make an `alias slink='sudo ln -sf'`, as [suggested by BANJOSA](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570104/364080), if I really want to use it

Comment: Yes, but I would not recommend hiding `sudo` inside an alias; it's tricky enough as is.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same! Thanks

Comment: if you create an alias for sudo, like i've said below ( `alias='sudo '` with the space after) and then you have your alias (`alias link='ln -sf'`) when you execute `sudo link` it will have the expected behavior. This way you are somehow not "hiding" the sudo command inside the ln alias.

Comment: @BANJOSA `alias='sudo '` just assigns to the `$alias` variable the `sudo ` string in my shell. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: please try it. it works for me, but the alias must have the extra space in the end.

Comment: @BANJOSA I don't see how that could work. Could you please give a complete example? `alias ll='ls -l'` and `alias='sudo '` followed by  `sudo ll` fails (as expected) with `sudo: ll: command not found` (I've tried this in a Debian 10 vm, vanilla config -- I don't usually install or use sudo ;-)).

Comment: it works on my ubuntu. can explain why

Comment: I've tried add exactly `alias='sudo '` in my `~/.bashrc`, but call of `link $1 $2` got the same result described in the question. I'm am at an Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Answer (score 1):

the issue here is that bash only evaluates the first word of a command for an alias and replace the text by the text of that alias.

when you do `sudo <your_alias>` , bash is only evaluating the first word which is the `sudo` itself and not expanding your aliased command.

A workaround would be create an alias for sudo itself

If you create an alias like `alias='sudo '`**(please be aware of the space after sudo command)** you can accomplish your desired command.

Comment: Thanks for the help again, @BANJOSA!